# Who are those who dwell in heavens?

Tags: revelation, heaven

In Revelation 12:12, we have this passage “Therefore rejoice, you heavens and you who dwell in them!” Heavens is the universe, so who dwells in it? Could God create other intelligent beings in our cosmos?

Also in this passage “You have made heaven, the heaven of heavens, with all their host... The host of heaven worships You.” (Nehemiah 9:6 ESV) it seems again it talks about some other beings, not angels.

Comment: Who says "Heavens is the universe", please? Whether or not there's a Hell, which religion teaches us that this, or any other world, is part of Heaven?

Quite separately, what restrictions do you want to place on God, preventing the creation of other intelligent beings, anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

In the OP, two verses are mentioned.

1. Revelation 12:12 - “Therefore rejoice, you heavens and you who dwell
   in them!”
2. Nehemiah 9:6 - “You have made heaven, the heaven of heavens, with
   all their host... The host of heaven worships You.”

In both of these verses there is a link between heaven and its "inhabitants", and the OP asks about the nature of those inhabitants.

But I think there is a misunderstanding here. We should not necessarily assume that inhabitants means intelligent beings such as people or angels. That may be the case, but it's far more likely that we have here normal Hebraic language describing creation at large.

Consider Psalm 148 as an illustration. The opening verses say:

Praise the Lord from the heavens;
praise him in the heights above.
Praise him, all his angels;
praise him, all his heavenly hosts.
Praise him, sun and moon;
praise him, all you shining stars.
Praise him, you highest heavens
and you waters above the skies.

Now what does "heavenly hosts" mean in line 4? Well, it could mean "angels", given that Hebrew poetry often repeats an idea with different words. Or it could be some kind of host different from the angels. Or, it could refer to the sun and moon and stars that appear in the following lines. What we cannot do is limit this based on the fact that this host praises God. The whole point of this psalm is that all creation, from the furthest star to the nearest flower, everything worships God in its own way.

We see a similar idea in Isaiah 45:12:

It is I who made the earth
and created mankind on it.
My own hands stretched out the heavens;
I marshaled their starry hosts.

The parallelism shows God creating the heavens and the earth, and in both cases it is a two part creation. God makes the earth, and he makes people to fill the earth. Likewise, God creates the heavens and he makes "the starry host" to fill the heavens. In that context "starry host" is surely just a poetic way to talk about the stars. God has made the heavens and filled them with stars. Read this way, we are simply following the outline of Genesis 1, in which God creates the heavens and the earth (day 1-3), then fills them with all kinds of creatures (including sun, moon and stars).

Finally, Nehemiah 9:6 itself supports this view. In the OP only part of the verse was quoted. But when we read the whole verse, we see there is a context which suggests a different meaning:

You alone are the Lord. 
You made the heavens, even the highest heavens, and all their starry host, 
the earth and all that is on it, 
the seas and all that is in them. 
You give life to everything, and the multitudes of heaven worship you.

This is part of a thanksgiving prayer offered to the God who has made all things. Creation is described in three part language: heavens, earth, seas. And in each case, God has made both the framework of creation and the creatures that inhabit that framework. When the prayer describes "the seas and all that is in them", what are we talking about? Surely the list would include fish, whales, plankton, crabs, sea horses, dolphins, sea weed, coral, barnacles, ice bergs... So it will be with the heavens. "The host of heaven" includes the sun, the moon, the rings of Saturn, the comets, black holes, galaxies, you name it. It will also include angels and other intelligent life, if any. But that's not the  point here. The prayer doesn't depend on us knowing the exact meaning of "hosts", because by definition everything is included.

Ultimately what we are doing here is applying a common sense approach to the natural literary meaning of the words used.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous references to other beings "in the heavens" or outside the earth as we know it such as:

- 1 Kings 22:19 - Micaiah continued, “Therefore hear the word of the LORD: I saw the LORD sitting on His throne, and **all the host of heaven** standing by Him on His right and on His left.
- Neh 9:6 - You alone are the LORD. You created the heavens, **the highest heavens with all their host**, the earth and all that is on it, the seas and all that is in them. You give life to all things, and the host of heaven worships You.
- Job 1:6, 2:1 - One day the **sons of God** came to present themselves before the LORD, and Satan also came with them. ... On another day the **sons of God** came to present themselves before the LORD, and Satana also came with them to present himself before Him.
- Job 38:4, 7 - Where were you when I laid the foundations of the earth? ... while **the morning stars** sang together and all **the sons of God** shouted for joy?
- Ps 33:6 - By the word of the LORD **the heavens** were made, And **all the host of them** by the breath of His mouth.
- Isa 34:4 - All the **host of heaven** shall rot away, and the skies roll up like a scroll. All their host shall fall, as leaves fall from the vine, like leaves falling from the fig tree.
- Isa 45:12 - It is I who made the earth and created man upon it. It was My hands that stretched out **the heavens**, and I ordained **all their host**.
- Luke 2:13 - And suddenly there appeared with the angel a great **multitude of the heavenly host**, praising God and saying:
- Rev 12:12 - Therefore rejoice, O **heavens, and you who dwell in them**! But woe to the earth and the sea; with great fury the devil has come down to you, knowing he has only a short time.”

[Note: the word "host" in the OT is צָבָא (tsaba) and means "army, war", etc.]

Note that whoever these beings are that inhabit the heavens, they are called by various names such as:

- "host of heaven"
- "multitudes of heaven"
- "sons of God"
- "morning stars"

Such beings presumably include angels (cherubim and seraphim and others?) and possibly others whose identity, function and characteristics are never stated.  The closest we get to a description of the throne room of heaven is in Rev 4 & 5 (presumably symbolic) where we have several classes of beings all praising God. [It appears that Satan came from among these heavenly creatures as hinted at in Isa 14:12-15, Luke 10:18, Rev 12:7-12.]

Further than this we cannot go.

Answer (score -1):

In order to understand the "who", we need to look at the context to understand the "where".

First, let's look at the word "heaven(s)" in the original languages.

**Hebrew שָׁמַיִם *shamayim* ([Strong's H8064](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/8064.htm))**
Brown-Driver-Briggs defines it as:

- visible heavens, sky, where stars, etc., are
- rarely of angels
- before which fowl fly
- as abode of God

**Greek οὐρανός *ouranos* ([Strong's G3772](https://biblehub.com/greek/3772.htm))**
Thayer's Greek Lexicon defines it as:

- the vaulted expanse of the Sky with all the things visible in it
- "the region above the sidereal heavens, the seat of an order of things eternal and consummately perfect, where God dwells and the other heavenly beings" in [2 Corinthians 12:2](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/2_corinthians/12-2.htm)

The topic of "[Heaven](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200001949)" in the *Insight on the Scriptures* gives a fuller definition of the concept that corroborates with both BDB and Thayer.

Within the context of Revelation 12:12, this is the spiritual realm where Jehovah God, Michael the archangel, all the other angels (including Satan the Devil) are located. In vss 7-9, we see Satan being cast out of heaven and therefore those "who dwell in them" would be spiritual beings (Jehovah, Michael, angels) that are righteous and faithful.

Jeremiah 9:6 breaks down "heaven(s)" into different locations:

- "made heaven", most likely the physical sky
- "the heaven of heavens", the spiritual realm

At the end of the verse, "the host of heaven" seems to be somewhat ambiguous. Different translations have different wording:

- *the angels of heaven*; New Living Translation
- *the heavenly lights*; New American Standard Bible
- *the stars of heaven*; Christian Standard Bible
- *the companies of Heaven*; Aramaic Bible in Plain English
- *praised by the stars that fill the heavens*; Contemporary English Version
- *The heavenly powers*; Good News Translation
- *the army of heaven*; International Standard Version, New Heart English Bible, World English Bible

The Hebrew word צָבָא *tsaba* ([Strong's H6635](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/6635.htm)) is used which is defined as army, war, warfare. So Jeremiah is most likely speaking about angels worshipping Jehovah God.